# How to use the new nsPredicate dynamic property of @FetchRequest property wrapper with object passed into View

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nspredicate

My first attempt was to set the property wrapper's `nsPredicate` dynamic property in `.onAppear`, but if the view gets reinitialized for any reason, the predicate set by `.onAppear` is lost. So I went back to using the init pattern.

Here is what I thought should work (but doesn't) and something that does work (however mysteriously):

```
struct ItemEditView : View {
    
    var item: Item
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Attribute.fetchRequestAllInOrder(), animation: .default)
    var attributes: FetchedResults<Attribute>

    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
        
        // This is how I would have expected to set the dynamic property at View initialization, however
        // it crashes on this statement
        attributes.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "item == %@", item)
        
        // Not sure why the below works and the above does not.
        // It seems to work as desired, however it receives this runtime warning:
        // "Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator"
        $attributes.projectedValue.wrappedValue.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "item == %@", item)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(attributes) { attribute in
                Text("Name:\(attribute.name) Order:\(attribute.order)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, why does the first assignment to nsPredicate crash?  And after commenting out that first one, why does the second one work?  Is the warning message a real issue? Is there a better way to do this?  It seems like there should be a simple way to do this using the new dynamic properties.

Comment: Why are you fetching the `item`? just wrap the passed value `@ObservedObject var item: Item`

Comment: What is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: The crash is:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Sorry, too many Items... Actually, I'm not fetching the Item. I'm fetching all of the Attribute's that are related to the Item passed into the View.  The Attribute entity has a relationship to the Item entity named "item".

Comment: Don’t you have a inverse relationship from Item to Attribute because then you don’t need a fetch request. Your list would be something like `ForEach(item.attributes) { attribute in` assuming the name of the inverse relationship is `attributes`

Comment: Yes, in the simplest case, the inverse relationship could be used instead.  However, when you add sorting and more complex filtering, it can be more straight forward to use a fetch request. I was hoping that the new dynamic properties would make it easier.

Comment: You can always create and/or set the predicate in onAppear

Comment: Setting the predicate in onAppear was the first thing that I tried.  However, if something causes the View to be reinitialized, onAppear is not called again and that new predicate is lost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a @FetchRequest with the new searchable modifier in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68530633/how-to-use-a-fetchrequest-with-the-new-searchable-modifier-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that (re)setting the `nsPredicate` property of the `@FetchRequest` in `onAppear` is really the way to go. However, to make this work, you must make sure that your View's `init()` method does not get called again after `onAppear` is called.  There are several valuable hints on how to accomplish this in the Demystify SwiftUI session from this year's WWDC (WWDC21-10022).

Comment: Bring CoreData concurrency addresses this exact thing with a custom Binding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68530633/how-to-use-a-fetchrequest-with-the-new-searchable-modifier-in-swiftui/68549693#68549693

Answer (score 0):

`FetchRequest` is a `DynamicProperty` that is only ready just before `body` is called which is before it is about to appear. If you implement a `DynamicProperty` yourself you'll see the `func update` which is called before the View's body is called and where it can access its own wrapped properties like `@State` and in the case of `FetchRequest` how it gets the `managedObjectContext` from the `@Environment`.

So to translate your 2 errors. The first one probably was "attempting to access property without being installed in a View" that is because it was used before `body` is ready to be called, i.e. it is not close to appearing yet. And the other one about not finding the context, is because it was accessed before its `func update` was called.

Another way to set the predicate is:

```
struct ItemEditView : View {
    
    let item: Item
    
    var request = FetchRequest<Attribute>(predicate: NSPredicate(value: false))
    var results: FetchedResults<Attribute> {
        request.wrappedValue.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "item == %@", item)
        request.wrappedValue.sortDescriptors = ...
        return request.wrappedValue
    }
```

An advantage to doing it this way is the predicate or sort could also use an `@State` like a search box or sort button.